# What and where is the easiest way to convert bitcoin back to cash without showing ID?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, privacy, mining-reward, sell-bitcoins

so im thinking about purchasing a big bitcoin miner, but the question now is how do i convert my BTC back to cash? I don't feel safe giving out my info to mtgox or other exchanges as they require identification. So what is the easiest way without having to go through a bunch of steps to conver it back to USD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The factors that matter for any cash-out decision are:

- Where are you located (country)?
- How much are you looking to trade?
- What type of cash are you looking to receive?
- How soon do you need access to the proceeds?
- Is privacy important?

In the U.S., [Coinbase](http://coinbase.com) might be the simplest -- you can sell up to 100 BTC per day, with a fee of 1% and then from there the USD proceeds are redeemed to your bank.  But that is a cash-out method using the banking system, so it is not anonymous or even close.

Other popular methods include [FastCash4Bitcoins.com](https://FastCash4Bitcoins.com) (now [BitSimple.com](https://BitSimple.com)), which can cash out to your PayPal, Dwolla, ACH (Direct Deposit), Bank Wire, Check, bank wire, or silver bullion.

For privacy, you might consider LocalBitcoins, in which a local cash transaction occurs, face-to-face.

- http://www.LocalBitcoins.com

There are dozens of cash-out methods:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins

Comment: I'd recommend LocalBitcoins.com if you're OK with a rate ~5-10% below market rate (generally bank deposit or sometimes in-person cash transactions). I have always bought my BTC thru LBC and sold as well, though it'll come down to location